# Perl scalar reference

Tags: perl, reference, scalar

I am trying to do some scalar reference work.  Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish. I am currently using perl 5.10.1.

Notes:

*color is dynamically obtained

*trying to get a say 100, or the red value

*I realize this is much easier done with a hash but how can I do it with scalars?

```
$red = 100;
$blue = 150;
$green = 200;

$color = "red";

say ${$color};
```

Current error = SCALAR ref while "strict refs"

Comment: See [Why it's stupid to use a variable as a variable name](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Comment: Would using a hash of colors be completely impractical? That's a much better way to tackle this.

Comment: It's not even a real scalar ref, that's why `strict` doesn't let you use it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because of `use strict`. You need to turn off `strict refs`.

```
no strict 'refs';
say ${"$color"}; # "" are optional, I want to show it's about the string
```

**Edit:** Note that this only works on **global** variables. So you need to declare them with `our` or `use vars` instead of `my`. This is documented in [perlfaq7](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name?) and shows why it is not a good idea to use variables to name other variables.

---

It's OK to turn off a `strict` feature in certain cases. But remember that it is good practice to contain it inside a very limited scope so it does not affect parts of your program that better not have this turned off.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

our $red = 100;
our $blue = 150;
our $green = 200;

my $color = "red";
{
  no strict 'refs'; # we need this to say the right color
  say ${$color};
}
# more stuff here
```

See also:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Not-so-symbolic-references
- http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/no.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name%3F

Comment: This working for anyone?  using this exact code block and say isn't outputting anything.  Also added ${"$color"} as he indicated at the top.

Comment: @tavor999 Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Also, the fact that I needed to go back and search for the problem for a few minutes is another argument for not doing this stuff! Ever!

Comment: thanks.  I would bump this up but I don't have enough cred yet :/

Answer (score 3):

Use a hash, that's what they're for:

```
my %color_value = (
    red => 100,
    blue => 150,
    green => 200,
);

$color = "red";

say $color_value{$color};
```

Otherwise, your error was reported because you just forgot to do [`no strict "refs";`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).  But please please [don't do that](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).

Comment: Thanks for fast response.  adding the "no strict" does allow it to continue without dying. I realize hashes are the obvious solution here but for other reasons I am curious if there is a solution using scalars/refs.  Still testing but using "no strict" still isn't finding it using  ${$color}

Comment: This is one area where curiosity didn't just kill the cat.  Honestly, if I found a coder using such a construct, I'd fire them.  There are not enough ways to say, just don't do that.

Comment: Thanks.  I wish I could up your response but I don't have enough cred yet.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers already given...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my $red = 100;
my $blue = 150;
my $green = 200;

my $color = \$red;

say ${$color};
```